# Glassfish server could not be started with JDK 16. Please select another Java SE platform

Tags: java, netbeans, server, glassfish

when I click on run, it displays this message in a dialog box.

' Glassfish server could not be started with JDK 16. Please select another Java SE platform.

And then it displays this error

Deployment error: Could not find Java SE Development Kit to start GlassFish Server
See the server log for details.

Is it a issue with glassfish version or jdk version? how can I fix this issue? any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked: "*Is it a issue with glassfish version or jdk version?*" - It's an issue with the *combination* of the GlassFish version and the JDK version that you are trying to use. For example, [see here](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.glassfish/downloads).

> "*GlassFish 6.2.5 ... officially supports JDK 11 ... runs on JDK 17 and JDK 18ea.*"

> "*GlassFish 6.1.0 ... supports JDK 11.*"

> "*GlassFish 6.0.0 ... only supports JDK 8.*"

And so on.

Going [farther back in time](https://glassfish.org/docs/5.1.0/release-notes/release-notes.html#abpak):

> "*GlassFish 5.1 requires Oracle JDK 8 Update 144 or later.*"

---

Generally speaking, unless you have a good reason not to do so, you should try to use a Java LTS (long-term support) release. You can see a  [list of recent and older JDK releases](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html), which shows which releases are LTS and which are not. LTS releases:

- 8
- 11
- 17

(But that does not mean GlassFish will not run on other versions. Follow the GlassFish release guidelines.)

---

You also tagged your question as a NetBeans question.

If you need to change the version of Java you are using in NetBeans, you can go to Tools > Java platforms > Add platform. But again, you may hit limitations where certain versions of NetBeans are not able to support certain versions of the Java JDK - so you need to check the NetBeans release guidelines for that.

For example for [NetBeans 14](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb14/nb14.html#_deployment_platforms):

> "*The Apache NetBeans 14 binary releases require JDK 11+, and officially support running on JDK 11 and JDK 17.*"

And going back to [NetBeans 9](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/):

> *"The main goals for this release are ... Java 9 and Java 10 Support."*